# Push a function into an array. why is the value of the array an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I push a setTimeout function into an array, when I console.log(arr), the value of the arr is an integer. Can anyone explain that for me! Thanks! The code is like this:

```
var arr=[];
arr.push(
 setTimeout(function(){
 $(selector).text(something);
 });
);
console.log(arr); // [2]
```

Also, I don't understand that purpose of pushing a function into an array! Can anybody help me with that as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not pushing a function into the array. You're **calling** `setTimeout()` and pushing the **return value** into the array.

Comment: Your not pushing a function, your pushing a setTimeout handle.

Comment: Because the return value of `setTimeout()` is an integer?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout  `"I don't understand that purpose of pushing a function into an array!"` - Well, if you wanted to have an array of functions, you could do just that.  But that's not what this code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout returns a timeout id, so in case you want to stop that timeout again you can do that by using clearTimeout(id).

You do not push a function in an array, but the result of the function execution (in this case the timeout id which is generated by setTimeout).

I also do not understand why you push it in an array, as the developer you should know it....!?

Comment: Thank you! The reason why i push it in an array is to use clearTimeout() later on!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the value you're putting in to the array is the identifier of the timer as returned from `setTimeout()`, which happens to be an integer. It's *not* the  jQuery object containing the input.

You need to rearrange your logic so that the `push()` is *inside* the `setTimeout()`:

```
var arr = [];
setTimeout(function() {
  arr.push($(selector).text(something));
  console.log(arr);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: $(selector).text(something) changes the text of the selector then why are you pushing that in the array?

Comment: That will return the jQuery object holding the selected object. It's valid to want to store that object reference in an array for use later, although the OP isn't clear about exactly what it is he want to do with it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

> I push a setTimeout function into an array,

No you don't. You push the result – its return value – of calling the `setTimeout` function into the array.

> Also, I don't understand that purpose of pushing a function into an arra

For instance you might want to call a function depending on the value of some index, or you are creating a stack or a queue of operations to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `objects` where you can associate a function to the object's key:

```js
var obj={};
obj.testFn = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     alert('invoked');
     //$(selector).text(something);
   },2000);
}

obj.testFn();
console.log(obj);
```